# Extracting column data from multiple line returns in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv, read-host

I have a CSV file with 3 columns: Name, Job, And Directory.

I'm trying to Have the user type in Either a Name, or a Job, and it will return one or multiple lines output from column 3 (Directories)

```
    $Profile = $PSScriptRoot + "\Profile.csv"
    $Data = Import-Csv -Path $Profile
    $JobChoice = Read-Host "Enter a Backup option"
    
$Results = $Data |  Where-Object {( $_.Name, $_.Job ) -eq [string]$JobChoice} 
     
$Results | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ($_.Directory)
```

The above example if I Type when prompted: "satisfactory"
it will only show one return. but it shows all three columns i just need it to return the current lines directory.

Also,
If I enter "SaveGame" as the Read-Host input. it will return all games with that job, but only the directories.
I Would like to keep this feature as it accepts one game or multiple based on if i choose Name, or Job

I have even tried every combination of:

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty ($_.Directory)
```

My goal of this is to add the data to the CSV then parse it and send them to xcopy to batch copy the returned directories.

Any help?

The CSV:

```
Name,Job,Directory
Satisfactory,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\Local\FactoryGame\Saved\SaveGames
TheLongDark,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\Local\Hinterland
TheInfected,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\Local\TheInfected
WrenchGame,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\Local\WrenchGame
Valheim,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\LocalLow\IronGate
RisingWorld,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\LocalLow\JIW-Games
7DTD,Savegame,C:\Users\jrkid\AppData\Roaming\7DaysToDie
```

Comment: Try `Where{$JobChoice -in $Data.Name -or $JobChoice -in $Data.Job}` and then it should be `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory`

Comment: "$Results = Where {$JobChoice -in $Data.Name -or $JobChoice -in $Data.Job} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory"   That Wont Return anything. I thought that would work. It makes sense.

Comment: Could you add your CSV as plain text instead of a screenshot to the question please?

Comment: Updated and added the CSV as Text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following statement, which can be read as:

An object of `$csv` **where** the value of the **Property** `Name` **OR** the value of the property `Job` are equal to `$JobChoice`. Then you can follow that statement with `.Directory` to enumerate all values of the `Directory` property.

See [Member Enumerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#member-enumeration) for details.

```
$csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv
$JobChoice = Read-Host "Enter a Backup option"
$csv.Where({ $JobChoice -eq $_.Name -or $JobChoice -eq $_.Job }).Directory
```

Looking back at your code, the statement you're currently using would also work too, however `-in` or `-contains` would be more efficient.

```
$csv.Where({ ($_.Name, $_.Job) -contains $JobChoice }).Directory
```

The only issue with your code was the use of `($_.Directory)`, it should have been just:

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting the Directory as the output?  Replace Select-Object with ForEach-Object and use {} instead of ()

```
$Results | ForEach-Object { $_.Directory}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code Was the solution i needed.

```
$csv.Where({ ($_.Name, $_.Job) -contains $JobChoice }).Directory
```

This allows me to extract the pipeline directory from the CSV File.
Below is the working script.

CSV

```
Name           Type     DirType    Directory                    
7DTD           Game      User     Roaming\7DaysToDie                    
ASXP        Application  User     Roaming\HiFi                  
BattleNet   Application  User     Local\Battle.net                  
CereProc    Application  User     Local\CereProc
```

Variables

```
$global:Profile = $PSScriptRoot + "\Profile.csv"
$global:Data = Import-Csv -Path $global:Profile
$global:BackupPath = "E:\PowerShell Scripts\Automate Backup\MainFrameV2\Test1"
$global:LogFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\Log.txt"
$global:AppData = $env:USERPROFILE+"\AppData"
$global:ProgramFiles = $env:ProgramFiles
$global:ProgramFiles86 = $env:ProgramFiles+" (x86)"
$global:ProgramData = $env:ProgramData
$global:DateFormat = "(%m-%d-%Y)"
$global:cWaitTime = 2 # Retry copy wait time

$global:TypeChoice = Read-Host
```

Robocopy With the Working Code

```
$global:Data | Where({ ($global:TypeChoice -eq $_.Type -or $global:TypeChoice -eq $_.Name) -and $_.DirType -eq "USER"}) | ForEach  {                   
                            robocopy ($global:AppData+"\"+$_.Directory) ($global:BackupPath +"\"+$global:Time+"\"+($_.Type)+"\"+ ($_.Name))  /S /mt:8 /tee /eta /log+:$global:LogFile /xf "*.ccc" /w:$global:cWaitTime
                            trap { exit 8 }
```